# How to search by category?

Tags: search, datagrid, vb6

It's me again. ^_^
Can I ask how can I filter a specific record by category? I only know how to filter only one category. Here's my code. Please help me. Thanks!

```
If txtName.Text = "" Then
MsgBox "Please enter what you want to filter.", vbInformation, "Message Box"
txtName.SetFocus

Else
If Not myRS.EditMode And myRS.BOF = True Then
MsgBox "No record found!", vbCritical, "Search Result"

Else
myRS.Filter = "TL LIKE '" & txtName.Text & "*'"
Set DataGrid1.DataSource = myRS

DataGrid1.Columns(0).Caption = "Work Group"
DataGrid1.Columns(1).Caption = "Team Leader"
DataGrid1.Columns(2).Caption = "Dept Head"
DataGrid1.Columns(3).Caption = "Participants"
DataGrid1.Columns(4).Caption = "Date Created"
DataGrid1.Columns(5).Caption = "Coach"
DataGrid1.Columns(6).Caption = "Problem"
DataGrid1.Columns(7).Caption = "Measure Impacted"
DataGrid1.Columns(8).Caption = "Status"
DataGrid1.Columns(9).Caption = "Where"
DataGrid1.Columns(10).Caption = "When"
DataGrid1.Columns(11).Caption = "How Much/Many"
DataGrid1.Columns(12).Caption = "Who"
```

Comment: Which type of recordset are you using? For ADO it would be something like this: "TL LIKE ... AND/OR XYZ LIKE ...". For further information you can have a look at the [ADO  Filter description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee275540(v=bts.10).aspx)

Comment: yes I am using ADO. how can I filter my record by category?

Comment: The line: myRS.Filter = ... IS how you filter the recordset.  From the rest of the code it looks like TL is the column name for Team Leader.  As you're code is written, you'll only ever be able to filter on TL.  To fix this, you'll need to build the .Filter string based on user input.  I'd suggest populating a list/combo box with field names for the user to select, then build the .Filter based on the selected text from the list/combo and the user input in txtName.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your query to populate myRS looks something like

```
Select WorkGroup, TL, DeptHead, ...., Category From blah blah
```

You could change your line to

```
myRS.Filter = "TL LIKE '" & txtName.Text & "*' OR Category LIKE '" & txtName.Text & "*'"
```

which would give you both TL and categories that match the txtName, or you could create a new text box in addition to txtName, perhaps txtCategory, and then change the line to

```
myRS.Filter = "TL LIKE '" & txtName.Text & "*' AND Category LIKE '" & txtCategory.Text & "*'"
```

Answer (score 0):

add a combo box in the form. and fill it

```
dim item 
Combo1.clear
For Each item In Array("Work Group", "Team Leader", "Dept Head" _
          , "Participants", "Date Created", "Coach"  _
          ,  "Problem", "Measure Impacted", "Status"  _
          , "Where", "When", "How Much/Many", "Who")

     Combo1.AddItem item
Next
```

then :

```
i=combo1.listindex
if(i=-1) then 
   'ErrorMessageHere
    exit sub
end if
myRS.Filter = "[" & myRS.Fields(i).Name & "] LIKE '*" & txtName.Text & "*'"
```

Comment: It gives this error "Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal." and highlighted this line
       **myRS.Filter = "[" & myRS.Fields(i).Name & "] LIKE '*" & txtName.Text & "*'"**

Comment: i guess myRS is a recordset, isn't it?

Comment: myRS.Filter =myRS.Fields(i).Name & " LIKE '*" & txtName.Text & "*'"

Comment: insert a [debug.print myRS.Filter = "[" & myRS.Fields(i).Name & "] LIKE '*" & txtName.Text & "*'" ] before it to check the string